# How to generate a DVI file in Windows?

Tags: dvi

I have a .tex file and I need to generate a DVI file from this. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 under windows. I tried TeXworks, TeXstudio, and Emacs but none of them produce the DVI file. I also run the command `latex document.tex` but also failed.

I got the error

```
! pdfTeX error (\pdfobj): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0).
\pgf@sys@setuppdfresources@plain ->\pdfobj
                                           reserveobjnum \edef \pgf@sys@pdf@...
l.418 \pgfutil@setuppdfresources
                                 % possibly call the above
No pages of output.
Transcript written on document.log.
```

Comment: What exactly is in that file? As you can see not everything is supported in non-pdf mode. So a minimal example, that procudes an error like this would be appreciated.

Comment: something in your file is forcing pgf (perhaps via tikz) to be in pdf rather than dvi mode, but unless you show your code it is hard to guess what is wrong with the code.  As you note, this will be unrelated to the editor you use to write the file (texworks/texstudio/emacs) and unrelated to the operating system (windows)

Comment: Based on your error file, you are using LaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX, please post your preamble portion of your TeX file for further analysing...

Comment: @MadyYuvi since pdflatex does not (by default) produce DVI output, it seems clear that the user is not using pdflatex